# dispose() calls are failing in a simple login Flutter app using Navigator

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, navigator

I've developed a simple Flutter app with a login route and 2 routes which are accesed once the user has logged in, but I'm facing errors when the user logout.

I've used Navigator and named routes. When the use logs in correctly, the login route is removed from the stack and the first route is pushed using `Navigator.popAndPushNamed()`. The second route is pushed using `Navigator.pushNamed()` from the first route and then poped to come back to the first route. The button to log out is in the second route and when it is pressed all routes are removed from the stack and the login route is pushed, using `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()`.

I'm getting two errors:

- Some timers which are initialized in initState() in first route and then cancelled in dispose() are not getting cancelled, they remain executing in login page.
- When the user re-login, the state of first route (Statefulwidget) appears as unmounted.
  I've read that named routes are discouraged, but I've not found equivalent Navigator methods to implement it using unnamed routes.

The flutter version is:

Flutter 3.7.12 • channel unknown • unknown source
Framework • revision 4d9e56e694 (7 weeks ago) • 2023-04-17 21:47:46 -0400
Engine • revision 1a65d409c7
Tools • Dart 2.19.6 • DevTools 2.20.1

I'm getting these errors using an emulator with Android API 31 and in debug mode.